# I want to replace all words that present in database to bold by matching.(PHP+MYSQL)

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, string, replace

I want to get bold words by comparing string with DB string and auto create hyperlink if words are similar to the string we entered.

```
$stringfetchfromdbtocompare = 'Microbiology is blah blah blah';
    //data string from DB to compare with the new string.

    $stringwanttocompare = 'Microbiology is a good subject blah';
    //data string compare to compare with db string.

    $array =  explode(' ', $stringfetchfromdbtocompare);
    //data string from db is exploded into words by space.

    foreach ($array as $item) {
        //data string from DB is converted into the single word($item).

        echo $replace=str_replace($item,"<b>$item</b>",$stringwanttocompare);

        echo '<br>';

    }
    //Result
    //Microbiology is a good subject blah
    //Microbiology is a good subject blah
    //Microbiology is a good subject blah
    //Microbiology is a good subject blah
    //Microbiology is a good subject blah
```

Comment: If there is  `a` then it would be - `Microbiology is <b>a</b> good subject bl<b>a</b>h`.

Comment: perhaps add spaces to the words being compared against?

Comment: Want to replace all words from my database in a string if would matched in a bold format.for example i have dictionary and have words like regard,best,male etc if there in any word present in a string would be converted into bold.